# How can I register JSR-356 Websocket in PAX-Web? (In bundle, not WAR)

Tags: websocket, osgi, karaf, jsr356, pax-web

I have a problem with the PAX-Web. I've tried to register a Websocket service as declrarative, but it is unaccessible from web. I've tried the given websocket-jsr356-6.0.3.war and it works fine. As I see the WAR file handles differently the org.osgi.service.http.HttpContext. I've tried the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1 - OSGi R6 Whiteboard HTTP method**

Creating a ServletContextHelper:

```java
package hu.blackbelt.judo.common.rest.regular;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper;
import org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(ServletContextHelper.class)
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME, value = "chat"),
        @Property(name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_PATH, value = "/test")
})
public class ChatServletContext extends ServletContextHelper {
}
```

And adding the Websocket Endpoint:

```java
package hu.blackbelt.judo.common.rest.regular;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;

import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(Object.class)
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_SELECT,
                value = "=(" + HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_CONTEXT_NAME + "=chat)")
})
@Slf4j
public class ChatEndpoint {

    public static final String ROOM = "room";

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(final Session session, @PathParam(ROOM) final String room) {
        LOGGER.info("session openend and bound to room: " + room);
        session.getUserProperties().put(ROOM, room);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        String room = (String) session.getUserProperties().get(ROOM);
        try {
            for (Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                if (s.isOpen()
                        && room.equals(s.getUserProperties().get(ROOM))) {
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendObject(chatMessage);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("onMessage failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The logs show me that the Endpoint is catched. I've debugged and Pax-Web is registering it.

The log shows the following line:

```
2017-05-04 02:36:02,698 | INFO  | Thread-70        | WebSocketTracker                 | 330 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-whiteboard - 6.0.3 | found websocket endpoint!!
```

But the websocket is unaccessible with the following URL: [ws://localost:8181/test/chat/testroom](http://ws://localost:8181/test/chat/testroom)

**Scenario 2 - Pax-Web properties on registered HttpContext (with JAX-RS it works)**

Creating HttpContext instance: (Utilizing the OSGi given Helper abstract class):

```java
package hu.blackbelt.judo.common.rest.regular;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.http.HttpContext;
import org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(HttpContext.class)
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = "httpContext.id", value = "chat"),
        @Property(name = "httpContext.path", value = "test")
})
public class ChatHttpContext extends ServletContextHelper implements HttpContext {
}
```

And the Websocket Endpoint:

```java
package hu.blackbelt.judo.common.rest.regular;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants;

import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

@SuppressWarnings({"checkstyle:missingctor", "checkstyle:illegaltoken"})

@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(Object.class)
@Properties(value = {
        @Property(name = "httpContext.id", value = "chat")
})
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat/{room}", encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class, decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class)
@Slf4j
public class ChatEndpoint {

    public static final String ROOM = "room";

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(final Session session, @PathParam(ROOM) final String room) {
        LOGGER.info("session openend and bound to room: " + room);
        session.getUserProperties().put(ROOM, room);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        String room = (String) session.getUserProperties().get(ROOM);
        try {
            for (Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                if (s.isOpen()
                        && room.equals(s.getUserProperties().get(ROOM))) {
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendObject(chatMessage);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("onMessage failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

But the websocket is unaccessible with the following URL: [ws://localost:8181/test/chat/testroom](http://ws://localost:8181/test/chat/testroom)

How can I achive that webcsocket be available? I do not want to repackage my bundle as WAB. Is there any way?

Comment: websockets via whiteboard aren't as trivial as expected, as it could be done in two ways. Though there is one test in the pax-web itests that should show how it could be done.